# Sort the strings in order from Case Upper to Lower

Tags: php

following list shuffled strings

```
"Apple", "Elephant", "Cat", "Banana", "Dog", "apple","elephant","banana","cat","dog"
```

Need to sorted as

```
"Apple", "apple", "Banana", "banana", "Cat", "cat", "Dog", "dog",...
```

i dont want to use  `natcasesort()` array sort

Comment: Did you at least try anything yourself before asking your question here? Post some code?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following-----

```
<?php

$animal= array(
    "Apple", "Elephant", "Cat", "Banana", "Dog", "apple","elephant","banana","cat","dog"
);
sort($animal, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
foreach ($animal as $key => $val) {
    echo "animal[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: am betting Uppercase and Lowercase Alternatively For Eg.. animal[0] = Apple animal[1] = apple animal[2] = banana animal[3] = Banana animal[4] = Cat animal[5] = cat animal[6] = dog animal[7] = Dog animal[8] = Elephant animal[9] = elephant

Comment: and i dont want array to sort